# Python create an empty sparse matrix

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to parse some real data into a `.mat` object to be loaded in my [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) script.

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object does not support item assignment

I found [coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix). However, I am not able to assign values to it.

**data.txt**

```
10 45
11 12 
4 1
```

I would like to get a sparse matrix of size **100x100**. And to assign 1's to

```
Mat(10, 45) = 1
Mat(11, 12) = 1
Mat(4, 1) = 1
```

---

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

def pdata(pathToFile):
    M = coo_matrix(100, 100)
    with open(pathToFile) as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            x, y = [int(v) for v in s]
            M[x, y] = 1     
    return M

if __name__ == "__main__":
    M = pdata('small.txt')
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: `coo_matrix` takes data parameters.  Check its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing this matrix with `coo_matrix`, using the (data, (rows, cols))` parameter format:

```
In [2]: from scipy import sparse
In [3]: from scipy import io
In [4]: data=np.array([[10,45],[11,12],[4,1]])
In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
array([[10, 45],
       [11, 12],
       [ 4,  1]])
In [6]: rows = data[:,0]
In [7]: cols = data[:,1]
In [8]: data = np.ones(rows.shape, dtype=int)
In [9]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(100,100))
In [10]: M
Out[10]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [11]: print(M)
  (10, 45)  1
  (11, 12)  1
  (4, 1)    1
```

If you save it to a .mat file for use in MATLAB, it will save it in `csc` format (having converted it from the `coo`):

```
In [13]: io.savemat('test.mat',{'M':M})
In [14]: d = io.loadmat('test.mat')
In [15]: d
Out[15]: 
{'M': <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Mon Aug  7 08:45:12 2017',
 '__version__': '1.0'}
```

`coo` format does not implement item assignment.  `csr` and `csc` do implement it, but will complain.  But they are the normal formats for calculation.  `lil` and `dok` are the best formats for iterative assignment.

Answer (score 11):

Use a sparse format, which supports efficient indexing, like [dok_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix)

> This is an efficient structure for constructing sparse matrices incrementally.
>
> ...
>
> Allows for efficient O(1) access of individual elements. Duplicates are not allowed. Can be efficiently converted to a coo_matrix once constructed.

The last sentence can be generalized to: can be efficiently converted to all the other common formats if needed.

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

M = dok_matrix((100, 100))  # extra brackets needed as mentioned in comments
                            # thanks Daniel!
M[0,3] = 5
```

Comment: You want `M = dok_matrix((100, 100))`.  It's also a mistake in the question.

Comment: Rendered my answer-in-writing obsolete. :/ As addition, if you absolutely would need the 'coo' representation, you can just do `M = M.tocoo()` as conversion at the end

Comment: np :) finding silly syntax errors is always easier in *other* people's code.  I just can never find them in my own.

Comment: @DanielF "Ah, it's 3 lines... Why should i test this... What could possibly go wrong" :-)