# Move sparse matrix from Matlab to Python numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new to Python, and I try to convert code from MATLAB to Python (numpy) .

I have the following code in MATLAB that create sparse matrix:

```
obj{i,j} = sparse(IR,IV,ones(length(val),1),length(ids{i}),length(vid{j}));
```

IR & IV are vectors.
What is the efficient way to implement that function in Python (numpy) ?
Thanks,
MAK

Comment: My answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547924/python-create-an-empty-sparse-matrix should work.  Get back to me if you have trouble translating the terminology from one to the other.

Comment: First, Thanks for your help! but, I try to use your example , but I received exception : my translation myNet=bsr_matrix((np.ones(len(u)),u,v),N,N) u,v are vector of size 8000 , and N  number of size 200 , I received exception of 'int' object is not iterable (in matlab this code work fine), May I put the input parameter opposite ? Thanks for your help

Comment: I would have tried `csr_matrix((np.ones(len(u)), (u, v)), shape=(N, N))`.  (I call this the `coo` style inpu.  The number of () is important.  `coo`, `csr` and `csc` take this style; `bsr` does not.

Comment: @hpaulj 4 Thanks!!.