# Creating sparse matrix using number signs from another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to create a sparse matrix with the number signs and coordinates from another matrix example:

```
A = array([[ 1  3 -2]
           [-3  4 -6]
           [ 4  7 -5]])

B = array([[1 2]
           [1 3]
           [2 3]
           [2 4]
           [2 5]
           [3 4]
           [4 5]])

Result sparce matrix:
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1[[ 1  -1   1   0.  0.  0.  0.]
2 [ 0.  0. -1   1   0. -1   0.]
3 [ 0.  0.  0.  1  -1   0.  1 ]]
```

The number of rows is defined by the number of rows in matrix A and the number of columns is defined by the number of rows of another matrix B, the numbers 1 or -1 are filled in according to the number of their respective column, example:

```
First row matrix A [ 1  3 -2 ]
Result sparse [ 1  -1   1   0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

1 first column, -1 second column, 1 third column and the remaining columns 0.
Should be done in this way on all rows. With matrix B must also be created an sparse matrix, but in another way for example:

The number of columns must be 5 and the number of rows is defined by the number of rows of matrix B. But in this matrix B all the numbers in the first column must assume (-), then it must be done in the same way as matrix A to create the sparse matrix for example:

```
B = array([[1 2]
           [1 3]
           [2 3]
           [2 4]
           [2 5]
           [3 4]
           [4 5]])

Result matrix B all numbers in the first column (-)
B = array([[-1 2]
           [-1 3]
           [-2 3]
           [-2 4]
           [-2 5]
           [-3 4]
           [-4 5]])

Result sparse matrix:
   1   2   3   4   5
1[ -1  1  0.  0.  0.]
2[ -1  0.  1  0.  0.]
3[ 0.  -1  1  0.  0.]
4[ 0.  -1  0.  1  0.]
5[ 0.  -1  0.  0.  1]
6[ 0.  0.  -1  1  0.]
7[ 0.  0.  0.  -1  1]]
```

I was prompted to use scipy.sparse.coo_matrix, tried several ways but could not do

Answer (score 0):

I just gave an example of making a sparse matrix in [Python create an empty sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547924/python-create-an-empty-sparse-matrix)

But for this case:

```
In [72]: A = np.array([[1,3,-2],[-3,4,-6],[4,7,-5]])
In [73]: A
Out[73]: 
array([[ 1,  3, -2],
       [-3,  4, -6],
       [ 4,  7, -5]])
```

Column numbers from the absolute value of `A` (but needs an offset)

```
In [74]: cols = abs(A.ravel())
In [75]: cols
Out[75]: array([1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7, 5])
```

Row numbers are just the `A` row number repeated

```
In [76]: rows = np.arange(A.shape[0]).repeat(3)
In [77]: rows
Out[77]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

And data is the sign of `A`.

```
In [78]: data = np.sign(A).ravel()
In [79]: data
Out[79]: array([ 1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1])
```

Feed these to the `coo_matrix` constructor.  Note that I use `cols-1` since indexing starts with 0, not 1:

```
In [80]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols-1)), shape=(3,7))
In [81]: M
Out[81]: 
<3x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [82]: M.A       # viewed as an array
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1]])
```

For calculations and many other actions, `sparse` will convert this to `csr` format.

todo - the `B` matrix